# Quick Action pop up window height in Lightning

Tags: popup-window, lightning-quickaction

I use standard Quick Action on an object with only one field on a layout. The field is lookup.
When I click on the quick action and start writing something to the lookup field, it shows quick results as usually also with an option to do Search or create new.
The issue is that in the small window of the quick action I can't see the lookup "drop-down," which makes it much less usable.

[image: quick action popup]

In previous releases, as a workaround, you could add blank spaces below the lookup field, making the pop-up bigger to reflect the number of fields/blank spaces, something like this:

[image: blank spaces]

But it doesn't work anymore after Winter'18, any ideas?

Comment: I think this is css problem .. can you share your css for blank div

Comment: @ManjotSingh he is not using custom component, this is a standard quick action link that he creates and then assign fields for the quick action page layout. I guess this is more a salesforce bug than anything else. Alternative solution is to create your own quick action and show it on the page

Comment: @Rao is right, it is not a custom component...